# variable cell is never mutated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I take var type variable then Xcode show warning

> variable is never mutated

If I take let type variable then don't show any result!

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource{
    let people = [
        ("Pankaj","Dhaka"),
        ("Asish","Madaripur"),
        ("Anup","Narail")
        ]
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "People"
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return people.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let (personName , personLocation) = people[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = personName
        cell.textLabel?.text = personLocation
        return cell
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
}
```

Comment: have you set the datasource proper on the tableview?  Are the datasource methods being called?  Is your tableview constrained properly so that it is actually onscreen with a non-zero size?

Comment: You are talking about two completely different issues. You can't use `var` because you never change `cell`. So once you fix that by using `let`, then you encounter an entirely different issue due to other coding problems.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a table view cell initialized with the default initializer `UITableViewCell()`

Reuse the cell, add an identifier (e.g. `PeopleCell`) in Interface Builder.

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PeopleCell", for: indexPath)
```

And make sure that `datasource` and `delegate` of the table view are connected in Interface Builder, too.